# Is it possible to compile a c/c++ mixed source code?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, g++

We have a c project, and want to combine a c++ project into this c project, and compile them into one binary, is it possible?

something like

```
cproject/src/
cproject/src/a.h
cproject/src/a.c
cproject/src/b.h
cproject/src/b.c
cproject/src/main.c
```

add cppproject

```
cproject/cppproject/src/c.h
cproject/cppproject/src/c.cpp
cproject/cppproject/src/m.h
cproject/cppproject/src/m.cpp
```

maybe compile cpp as a shard library and link it?

Comment: No, you can't have two `main()` functions even with one language, and definitely can't have them in different languages. You also can't have multiple files with the same name in the same project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefile with mixed c and C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105358/makefile-with-mixed-c-and-c-code)

Comment: @KenWhite Huh? You certainly can have multiple source files with the same name but different directories.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely is possible. With proper usage of `extern "C"` you can call C functions from C++ code, and vice-versa -- even linked into the same binary.

Comment: If you're careful, it should work OK as long as you link with the C++ compiler rather than the C compiler.  That's certainly the case traditionally.  It might be that you can get away with mixed linking even with a C compiler, but C++ has a lot more setup.  You should probably have the `main()` function as C++ code, even if it is simply `int main(int argc, char **argv) { return c_main(argc, argv); }` — that is, it simply calls a (renamed) C function that implements the `main()` functionality.

Comment: C and C++ source files mixed in one library - can be found e.g. in a C++ library with C binding (i.e. a C API)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You say You have a project in C and another in C++.
But the way you would resolve (" shard library and link it?") is another thing.

As other people noted You can:

1) mix C and C++ (using carefully *extern "C"* )

2) make a project with a subproject (in Xcode for Mac is a standard practice to add project to an existing project

3) be sure there is only one main()

4) You you want to do an external lib, no need to mix them, but exposing methods, managing includes andlinkage options and passing parameters can be a bit complex if You are not experienced.

Libs and DLL are very different from a normal "main()" program.